# ¿Alguien puede puede orientarme a realizar una consulta en MYSQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi duda es la siguiente, yo tengo una tabla la cual cuenta con **empleados**, **un turno asignado**, y el **id día** que conforma ese turno. Entonces se puede tener dos empleados iguales pero con distinto turno asignado.

Cómo puedo obtener por ejemplo, el **turno 25** del **empleado 62**, ya que tiene dos turnos asignados?.

Gracias.

```
SELECT *
FROM turno
WHERE idturno = (SELECT idturno
                FROM dia_turno
                WHERE idturno = (SELECT idturno
                                FROM empleado_turno
                                WHERE idempleado = 62)
                )
AND (SELECT iddia
    FROM empleado_turno
    WHERE iddia = 'LUNES')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz intentado algo? Edita tu pregunta y muéstranos un poco del query que tienes hasta ahora. Tal como está formulada tu pregunta no cumple con las normas de la comunidad y podría terminar cerrada.

Comment: Ahi la he editado con lo que hice, y lo que me retorna

Comment: Facundo, gracias por editar tu respuesta. De igual manera te invito a que hagas [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas como funciona la comunidad.

Comment: fijate con un group by y lo agrupas por id del turno y  id del empleado

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta realizar sub-consultas para encontrar la información que quieres obtener. Lo puedes hacer con una consulta mucho más sencilla.

Empecemos por lo básico:

Puedes obtener el registro que te interesa de de la tabla `empleado_turno` aplicando las condiciones del `idempleado` y el `iddia` que has mencionado, por ejemplo:

```
select *
  from empleado_turno
 where idempleado = 62
   and iddia = 1
```

o LUNES, pero veo en los datos que es un número, así que asumo que el 1 es el Lunes.

Esto nos va a devolver los registros que coincidan con ser del empleado 62 y día lunes, que según se ve en tus datos, es solo uno.

Luego, si lo que necesitas son los datos de una hipotética tabla `turno` (que no muestras, pero que *mencionas* en tu consulta), relacionada a este registro, puedes obtener los datos de esta tabla haciendo *join* con la de `empleado_turno`, aplicando las mismas condiciones del primer ejemplo. Esto nos va a filtrar para ver solamente el registro que nos interesa.

En código, luciría algo así:

```
select turno.*
  from empleado_turno
       inner join turno on turno.idturno = empleado_turno.idturno
 where empleado_turno.idempleado = 62
   and empleado_turno.iddia = 1
```

Observa como en esta segunda consulta he calificado los nombres de las columnas para indicar sin ambigüedad a qué tabla pertenecen mis referencias.